# How to write a test with this ActiveRecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I have a `Task` model which has several params, one of which is `user_ids` which allows for multiple users to be added to a task.  This is done with a `has_many: :users, through: assigned_users`

The actual controller action works fine but I am refactoring to have better test coverage. I can save tasks in the app but the test always throws this error (full stack trace below):

```
Error:
TaskTest#test_task_can_save:
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
    test/models/task_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:TaskTest>'
```

A very basic test should be that tasks can save:

require 'test_helper'

```
class TaskTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @usr = users :joe

    @task = Task.new(comments: "Basic task", project_id: 1, subproject_id: 2,
                      day: "2019-01-09", time: 55, user_ids: [@usr.id])
  end



   test "task can save" do
     assert @task.save "task should save"
   end
  end
```

This is the *working* `create` action.

**tasks_controller**

```
def create

@task = current_user.tasks.build(task_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @task.save
    current_user.tasks << @task
    @tasks = current_user.tasks
    format.js {flash[:notice] = "Task added"}

   else
     ...

end

private
  def task_params
     params.require(:task).permit(:comments, :project_id, :subproject_id, :day, :time, user_ids: [])
 end
```

Tasks save and everything work, just not this test.  I've tried other things in the `user_ids:` hash for example `[User.first.id]`, and `[1]` everything seems to give the same error.

```
un options: --seed 2048---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=] 0% Time: 00:00:00,  ETA: ??:??:??

# Running:

ERROR["test_task_can_save", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x007f8f9016b3c8 @name="TaskTest">, 0.38674699992407113]
 test_task_can_save#TaskTest (0.39s)
TypeError:         TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
            test/models/task_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:TaskTest>'

  1/1: [==========================================================================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00
E

Error:
TaskTest#test_task_can_save:
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
    test/models/task_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:TaskTest>'


/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb:70:in `method': undefined method `test_task_can_save' for class `Minitest::Result' (NameError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb:70:in `format_rerun_snippet'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb:23:in `record'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:803:in `block in record'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:802:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:802:in `record'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:334:in `run_one_method'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:321:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:320:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:320:in `block in run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:360:in `on_signal'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:347:in `with_info_handler'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:319:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/test_unit/line_filtering.rb:9:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `block in __run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `map'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `__run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:136:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `fork'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `serve'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: btw, you don't need the line `current_user.tasks << @task`, @task already belongs to current_user, since it is `current_user.tasks.build(task_params)`

Comment: And could you please add the full error stacktrace? Which line in task_test.rb is under 14?

Comment: I added the stack trace, line 14 is where `@task.save` occurs.

Comment: Did you miss comma in `assert @task.save, "task should save"` only in the question, or it is missed in the real test too?

Comment: Oh thanks that's a good catch.  Although I'm still getting that error.  Interestingly enough now the error has changed, I'm just getting `Failure:TaskTest#test_task_can_save: Expected false to be truthy.` I will look into that.

Comment: I believe the issue was that I was not pulling in a project fixture.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was an issue with the `project_id:` since I had not setup a project in the `setup` method.

I had to pull a `Project` in from the projects fixture:

```
def setup
    @usr = users :joe
    @project = projects :projectOne
    @task = Task.new(comments: "Basic task", project_id: @project.id, subproject_id: 2,
                      day: "2019-01-09", time: 55, user_ids: [@usr.id])
  end
```